# column titles for histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am a newbie on the website and novice in using matplotlib. I have a data frame train_data with columns 'age' and 'survived'. I have made the histogram with the following code and it is perfect for my need.

```
    fig=plt.figure()
    train_data.hist(column='Age',by='Survived',stacked=True,bins=20)
    plt.xlabel('Age')
```

[image]

The problem is I want both graphs to have Xlabel= Age and instead of 0,1. Survived =0 & survived=1. Can anyone help me out with this Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the axes objects to work specifically with each one, try adding:

```
axarr = fig.axes
axarr[0].set_title('Survived = 0')
axarr[0].set_xlabel('Age')
axarr[1].set_title('Survived = 1')
axarr[1].set_xlabel('Age')
```